# Error inflating class fragement

Tags: android-manifest

i am trying to find out this problem from last one month i have seen lots of post about it but no solution found till now.
i used google-play-services, support lib file, but fragament error still there;
i want to use google map but follwoing error occure always;
this is MainActivity

```
package com.example.finalmap;                
                import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.app.Activity;
                import android.view.Menu;

                public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }

                }
```

This is androidmanifest

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       package="com.example.finalmap"
                       android:versionCode="1"
                       android:versionName="1.0" >

                       <uses-sdk
                           android:minSdkVersion="17"
                           android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
                       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                       <application
                           android:allowBackup="true"
                           android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                           android:label="@string/app_name"
                           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                           <uses-library  android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
                           <activity
                               android:name="com.example.finalmap.MainActivity"
                               android:label="@string/app_name" >
                               <intent-filter>
                                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                               </intent-filter>
                           </activity>
                           <meta-data
                            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                               android:value="" />
                       </application>

                   </manifest>
```

Activity_main

```
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

to

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.finalmap.MainActivity" -> add this line
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And if you are using Google Maps V2, change it from `MapActivity` to `FragmentActivity`, and 
`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` to `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`